# Why do some tools / scripts not open for use in the ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst, landsat, land-classification

I am using the Image Classification toolbar to classify a composite LANDSAT image and every time I go to the "classification" drop down and chose the "Iso Cluster Unsupervised Classification" option the tool fails to open and gives the following message:

"Failed to open tool IsoClusterUnsupervisedClassification (Spatial Analyst Tools)"

Also, when I try to run the tool using the search option and then choose the script for this tool that fails to open.

It is strange, every other tool within the tool bar works - I need this tool to give a raster output. I am using ArcGIS 10.1.

[image: Error Message when try to use the Iso Cluster Unsupervised Classification tool from the image classification toolbar]

Comment: Do you have the spatial analyst toolbox turned on?  From the Customize menu in ArcMap select Extensions.  Is 'Spatial Analyst' checked?

Comment: The option on the toolbar is a link to the geoprocessing tool. Update your question with a picture of how you fill in the tool for it to fail?

Comment: Yes, Spatial Analyst is turned on - other tools related to the extension work.

Comment: I can't fill in the tool tool when I try to use it I either get no response (from the searched tool) or the message shown on the image attached and mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer - I just needed to find the drive and folder location for the script "IsoClusterUnsupervisedClassification.py" right click in the ArcToolbox>Add Toolbox>Scripts (where the script was located) and the tool works fine.

For some reason, the tool / script I was using was not finding the tool.  All very confusing - but with a little messing around - this works.